# Not able to sleep on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, gdm

Im running Ubuntu 20.0.4 with Ryzen 5 5600x.

As soon as i click suspend button the pc its suspended only for 1 second and turned up again. The monitors go off but computer never go off.

I managed to check the processes that are keeping pc awake.

```
systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
```

Result below:

```
gdm 125  gdm  39766 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses block
s   1000 s    40949 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses block
```

[ 6502.691600] PM: suspend entry (deep) [ 6502.697232] Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds [ 6502.697373] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done. [ 6502.699478] OOM killer disabled. [ 6502.699478] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done. ..... [ 6505.057746]

OOM killer enabled. [ 6505.057747] Restarting tasks ... done. [ 6505.061579] PM: suspend exit [ 6505.276597] rfkill: input handler disable

Comment: Ryzen 5 5600x is known to have issues with Modern Standby support (s2idle). If this is the cause of the problem, a quick fix would be to check UEFI firmware settings if it is possible to disable Modern Standby and enable s3 support instead. More info: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230

Comment: Its not ryzen issue. My pc is dual boot with windows. In windows is sleeping after some times of inactivity. Its a ubuntu issue guess.

Comment: It is an AMD issue that they did not release a driver for Linux Kernel to render Modern Standby with their product properly.

Comment: What is your `dmseg` starting with `PM: suspend entry` and ending with `PM: suspend exit`?

Comment: [ 6502.691600] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[ 6502.697232] Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds
[ 6502.697373] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[ 6502.699478] OOM killer disabled.
[ 6502.699478] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
.....
[ 6505.057746] OOM killer enabled.
[ 6505.057747] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 6505.061579] PM: suspend exit
[ 6505.276597] rfkill: input handler disable

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Do you still have the issue? Similar problem gone for me with an update at the kernel version 5.14.14 on Fedora for Ryzen 5 4500U.